# Python changing global variable

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm trying to create a function in Python 3 that can edit multiple variables, for example

```
    x = 1
    y = 2
    def addOne(x1):
        x1 = x1 + 1
    test(y)
    print(y)
```

is there any way that I could make this work so that addOne can edit any variable put in to this?

Comment: ...but do you know that integers are *not mutable*?

Answer (score 0):

If the variable are global you could do it like this

```
x = 1
y = 2

def addOne(x1):
    globals()[x1] = globals()[x1] + 1

addOne('y')
print(y)
3
```